# Modifying Delphi's own *.DCU files

Tags: delphi

I have taken Controls.pas and copied it to Control1.pas and done the same with the files its dependant on, so it complies. I found some minor errors to repair and I added one procedure, in TWinControl, Protected, marked it virtual. Compiled it and then renamed Control1 to Controls and the dependant files in the DCU back to original (so not changing the file size). This added procedure, through its name should have no effect on the rest of Delphi that depends on it. 
  I replaced of the original Lib\Controls.DCU and my new procedure is not seen or available in the IDE. I guess I have to get this in a *.BPL file somewhere but do not know how or were. Am I correct so far to put my update in like this.

Comment: You have modified code that so many other packages are dependant on. Without being able to rebuild all those other packages you are bound to run into issues. Unfortunately it seems a futile exercise

Comment: Why? What issue were you thinking to solve?

Comment: Plus by default Delphi projects compile whithout the "Compile using debug DCU's" disabled, so there are two versions of the default dcu's to replace. But since they're used by much more than your application it is indeed a bad idea.

Comment: You have recompile the entire VCL since you've changed the interface. You'd normally try to avoid doing so.

Comment: *Am I correct so far*: No. You've done exactly the wrong thing, which is to modify parts of the base VCL that does not belong to you, and then expect it to have no effect on the rest of the VCL (that also does not belong to you). You can't alter the interface of a unit without every single unit that uses it needing to be recompiled, and that would include every runtime package that's part of the standard VCL. IOW, you've borked everything unless you put things back like they were. There is undoubtedly a better solution than the one you've chosen, but you've not provided info to tell how.

Comment: I've been raised with comments of dealt, but to find if it works is, do I have a *.BPL file to rebuild or something for the compiler to use my new file.

Comment: The reason I'm doing it to to gain access to a hidden part of TWinControl that listed in private. so I do not see any other option. If Controls.pas was not given to me then it would not belong to me. The issue is what package does Controls.dcu belong too.

Comment: If I can do this, you will be amazed at this new feature, it will become more common than products like Toolbar2000 in time.

Comment: How dose one view contents of a *.BPL file is a good question I believe to start with?

Comment: Access the private members with a class helper, or RTTI. You aren't going about this the right way. You certainly don't understand linking process enough to get the details right. You are asking the wrong questions. For the record you aren't allowed to distribute RTL/VCL/FMX standard libraries in your packages.

Comment: Copyright laws says it does belong to me, I'm interested in *.BPL, DCU files, unless you have some statement from embarco that says other wise David Heffernan. Why do you not address what RTL/VCL/FMX standard libraries are and what they mean to this project

Comment: I found under the IDE/component/install component  a Controls.Pas held in VCL.dcp file. I think I need to rename it back to *.DCU.

Comment: No, the Embarcadero licence is clear. You need to stop guessing and start listening. The simple way to solve your problem is to crack the class, access the privates, and not modify library code.

Comment: you need to start giving details on this subject, referances

Comment: There are plenty of questions that discuss cracking privates

Comment: Regarding the license, you have it, you accepted it. The RTL, VCL, etc. packages are redistributables. You are granted rights to redistribute them, unmodified.

Comment: Still have not legitimised your comment!!!!!!!!!!!!!!.  RTL and VCL you have raised the discussion but I'm not near any of that stuff to my knowledge. I have now found credible large web sites that explain what I need now and realise the file is stored in *.BPL files.